Benchmarking using WebApplicationFactory
We are looking into doing some benchmarking work for some REST API endpoints that are part of a .NET 6 project using a tool like BenchmarkDotNet.
We appreciate that a tool like BenchmarkDotNet is best suited to benchmarking individual classes. But sometimes we need to look into things like memory usage for an API endpoint where we don't initially know where any memory inefficiency might be coming from.
For these situations we'd ideally have a set-up that enables us to invoke the API locally while we iterate on ideas and monitor the overall memory usage.
One way to do this is to use WebApplicationFactory to invoke the endpoint in the same way we would do for integration tests. However our question is would this be valid or would we be measuring the memory usage for calling the API rather than what is being consumed by the API itself?
